# Given a list and a bitmask, how do I return the values at the indices that are True?

Tags: python, list, sequence, tuples, bitmask

I start with the following list `s` and bitmask `b`:

```
s = ['baa', 'baa', 'black', 'sheep', 'have', 'you', 'any', 'wool']
b = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] # or any iterable with boolean values
```

How do I write some function `apply_bitmask(s, b)` so that it returns

```
['baa', 'have', 'you', 'any']
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Python 3.1 [itertools.compress](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) (or [Python 2.7's](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) if you haven't upgraded yet) does exactly that (the list comprehension is a real close second):

```
import itertools
filtered = itertools.compress(s, b)
```

Note that this produces an iterator, not a list. Saves memory, but if you need to iterate it several times or use indices, you can always use `list(itertools.compress(s, b))`. Still shorter.

Comment: @Kit: Only if you copypaste the example definition given in the documentation (or simply adapt it right away, i.e. `result = (i for i, flag in itertools.izip(s, b) if flag)` (zip in Python 3 is izip in Python 2, it's a lazy iterator instead of a list)).

Answer (score 11):

```
[ item for item, flag in zip( s, b ) if flag == 1 ]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
newList = [word for (word, mask) in zip(s,b) if mask]
# Note: Could also use 'if mask == blah', if mask is not a boolean-compatible type.
```

This first takes the original two lists, and [zips](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) them together, so that you get a (temporary - this is still inside the list comp!) list of pairs of words and their masks - something like `[('baa',1), ('baa',0),...]`. Then only the words that have a mask of 1 (`if mask == 1`) are added to the `newList`.

Comment: Though I'd use `... if mask`, since he asked about true values, not about `1` specifically.

Comment: That is true. I shall add it to the answer. Thanks delnan.

Answer (score 0):

Another take on list comprehension, witout using zip

```
newList = [item for i, item in enumerate(s) if b[i]]
```